# Binding User control elements to Model properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to bind a `UserControl` to some model with no luck.

I have this `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="spPatientFiles" Grid.Row="2"
              ItemsSource="{Binding PatientFiles, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type uc:PatientFile}">
         <uc:PatientFile/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <ItemsControl.DataContext>
      <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
   </ItemsControl.DataContext>
</ItemsControl>
```

It is bound by

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PatientFile> PatientFiles { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        PatientFiles = new ObservableCollection<PatientFile>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Models.LocalSettings.SaveFolder) &&
            System.IO.Directory.Exists(Models.LocalSettings.SaveFolder))
        {
            var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Models.LocalSettings.SaveFolder);

            foreach (var p in files)
            {
                var n = p.Substring(p.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, p.LastIndexOf(".") - p.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1);
                var ext = p.Substring(p.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);

                PatientFiles.Add(new PatientFile()
                {
                    FileName = n,
                    Path = p,
                    FileType = ext == "avi" ? OutputType.Video : OutputType.Image
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main xaml has View Model:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Octopus.Capturing.ViewModels"x:Class="Octopus.Capturing.Views.MainApp"
        ...>
```

This is my `UserControl` (`uc:PatientFile`)

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:Octopus.Capturing.Models"
             x:Class="Octopus.Capturing.Views.Controls.PatientFile"
             ... >
 
<Label FontSize="10" 
       VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"
       Content="{Binding FileName}"/>
```

But the binding doesn't work.
When I run the app I get the structure of the `UserControl` (style and correct number of files read from folder) but without the binding to the file name property.

What i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You should use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` to process file by file. This results in better performance as you can handle each file immediately as it is read. `Directory.GetFiles` will read all files first just to iterate the results a second time in order to process them. Don't do this in your constructor, but e.g., just before the user control is shown. `StackPanel` iss the default panel of `ItemsControl. You don't need to define it explicitly.

Comment: You are currently creating two `PatienFile` user controls for each file item: one in the view model (which you shouldn't do) and one in the `DataTemplate`. Replace the user control in your view mode with a model type. `ItemsControl` should always bind to a collection of data items. And you never instantiate or handle controls in a view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have a collection of `PatientFile` `UserControl`s in a view model. Instead, create a separate view model for this kind of user control, `PatientFileViewModel`. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to enable notifying the controls to update the changed properties.

```
public class PatientFileViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _fileName;
   public string FileName
   {
      get => _fileName;
      set
      {
         if (_fileName == value)
            return;

         _fileName = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   // ...implement the other properties like this, too.

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

Adapt your `ItemTemplate` to display the `PatientFile` user control for the `PatientFileViewModel`.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type uc:PatientFileViewModel}">
      <uc:PatientFile/>
   </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Next, remove the properties and code that is now in the view model from your `PatientFile` user control. You can keep its XAML code. The content of the `Label` will now be bound to the data context, which is the `PatientFileViewModel` that is set by the `ItemsControl` automatically when applying the `DataTemplate`.

Finally adapt your `MainViewModel` to create and use `PatientFileViewModel`s instead of `PatientFile`s.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
   public ObservableCollection<PatientFileViewModel> PatientFiles { get; set; }

   public MainViewModel()
   {
      PatientFiles = new ObservableCollection<PatientFileViewModel>();

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Models.LocalSettings.SaveFolder) &&
          System.IO.Directory.Exists(Models.LocalSettings.SaveFolder))
      {
         var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Models.LocalSettings.SaveFolder);

         foreach (var p in files)
         {
            var n = p.Substring(p.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, p.LastIndexOf(".") - p.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1);
            var ext = p.Substring(p.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);

            PatientFiles.Add(new PatientFileViewModel()
            {
               FileName = n,
               Path = p,
               FileType = ext == "avi" ? OutputType.Video : OutputType.Image
            });
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Make sure that you set the `DataContext` of your main view to the `MainViewModel`, e.g.:

```
<Window xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Octopus.Capturing.ViewModels"x:Class="Octopus.Capturing.Views.MainApp"
        ...>
   <Window.DataContext>
      <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
   </Window.DataContext>
   <!-- ...other code. -->
</Window>
```

Furthermore, you should remove `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the `ItemsSource` binding, it is not needed.